# jQuery remove all characters after ? in img src

Tags: jquery, regex, image, replace, src

Would like to modify img src from:

```
<div class="solo">
  <img src="/uploads/2016/08/Simone-B.jpg?fit=97%2C146&amp;ssl=1">
</div>
```

To:

```
<div class="solo">
  <img src="/uploads/2016/08/Simone-B.jpg">
</div>
```

Tried using the following but not working:

```
jQuery('.solo img').each(function(){
     jQuery(this).attr('src',jQuery(this).attr('src').replace('?*',''));
});
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code `.replace('?*','')` replace string `?*`. For removing that particular part you need to use regex instead like `.replace(/\?.*/,'')`.

But the better way is to use **[`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method with a callback for iterate and update based on the old value.  Where you can use **[`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** method for removing the string part after `?` in the attribute value.

```
jQuery('.solo img').attr('src',function(i,v){
   return v.split('?')[0]; // get the string part before the `?`
   // or 
   // return v.replace(/\?.*/,'');
});
```

Comment: Great solution and clean code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JoseSalazar : glad to help :)